# Select top 1000 rows in MySQL Workbench And Generate List of Headers

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I previously used `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio` and when I right clicked on a table and selected `Select top 1000 rows` a new tab would open created.

Inside that tab, some code would be generated automatically and would contain the list of headers (in TSQL syntax) within the select statement:

[image]

I really liked this feature because it meant that I didn't have to write out all of the headers every time.

However, when I do this equivlant step (of right clicking on a table and clicking on 'Select Rows - Limit 1000') in `MySQL Workbench 6.3.3`, the code that is generated only has the * operator. For example, a new tab would be created and only has this sytax within it:

SELECT * FROM data.table;

The * operator can be used instead of writing all of the column headers but I would like have `MySQL Workbench 6.3.3` generate all of the table headers.

Is it possible to change a `MySQL Workbench 6.3.3` setting so that it performs in the same way as `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`?

Comment: what mysql client are you using?

Comment: What is the definition of the "top 1000"? Don't you think whatever it is, Oracle does not have to share that with MS.

Comment: You could use a query with LIMIT keyword to limit the number of results

Comment: Or maybe what you mean is to add `ORDER BY id DESC`? (Workbench adds a limit of 1000 automatically to `SELECT` queries.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/240291/how-to-remove-1000-row-limit-in-mysql-workbench-queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of choosing "*Select Rows - Limit 1000*", select "*Send to SQL Editor*" and then choose "*Select All Statement*". Or, instead of "*Send to SQL Editor*" you could do the same with "*Copy To Clipboard*".

In either case, a full query is generated as you desire, although it is not executed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

select * from Broker order by BrokerID desc LIMIT 1000